# tshark conversation statistic not resolving hostnames

Tags: ip, wireshark, tshark, statistics

Executing the `-z conv,ip` command does not display the hostnames (like in wireshark).
I execute the command, and after a bit of traffic was monitored, I stop tshark with Ctrl-C and then the conversation table is printed. For both Linux and Windows, the messages displayed before the conversation table correctly show hostnames, only the conversation table doesn't have them.

**Linux:**

- command: `tshark -i 1 -N n -f "tcp or udp" -z conv,ip`
- OS: Fedora 17 x86
- tshark version: 1.6.12
- Solutions tried:

  1. Ommiting `-N`
  2. Using `-N C`

**Windows:**

- command: `tshark -i 2 -f "tcp or udp" -z conv,ip`
- OS: Windows 7 x64
- tshark version: 1.8.4
- Solutions tried:

  1. Ommiting `-N`
  2. Using `-N C`
  3. Using `-N n` causes tshark error out on Ctrl-C: (tshark.exe:9692): CaptureChild-WARNING **: signal_pipe_capquit_to_child: 4 header: error Invalid argument

How do I make tshark -z conv,ip display resolve hostnames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tshark showing resolved hostnames in the conversation statistic does not appear possible.

An alternative is to execute the following commands:

```
tshark -i 1 -N n -e ip.host -E separator=, -f "tcp or udp" -l > tshark_buffer

sort -u tshark_buffer -o tshark_buffer
```

Where the first command dumps packet information into a file named `tshark_buffer`, and the second command eliminates duplicate entries. The packet information is stored in the form `host1,host2` on each line. However, the duplicate elimination will not catch entries with the hosts reversed (i.e. `host2,host1`).